# No postback on click in IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, postback

I have an `asp:button` which works fine in all browsers except IE8. When I click the button nothing happens. It seems like the page doesn't detect that it should post the page.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried the Developer Tools script debugger?

Comment: Could be a few things; client script that doesn't work in ie8, validation on page firing at wrong time, etc. You are going to have to post code before anyone can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Try writing any other kind of javascript code to your page, if it does not work then you know that there is something wrong with your browser not running js, therefore not finding/running the dopostback function.

Comment: It seems that the problem was connected to a OnClientClick. I has a validation function that should run before the page being submitted and that did not work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might happen when there is a script error in the page during page load. I my case, the error happened in Google Analytics file because the Google stopped supporting IE8.

I know this question has been asked a while ago but my experience might help someone out there who is facing the same issue.